# How do I reduce the header height in Garland?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I want to get rid of the space below my header logo in Garland.
I know the header is 80 pixels tall, but when I try changing that value it messes up other things.

I want to reduce the dark colored section below my logo (which is empty) by 20 pixels, and also get rid of the lighter colored section that appears just above the main column (and is about 20 pixels tall).

You can see my site on http://www.energyjustice.net.

Comment: so um, I see you've updated your site... it would be cool if my answer was accepted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the background css properties on the "right corner" and "left corner" divs. Next, remove just the url section in the background property in the "squeeze" div.

Add this to the "squeeze" div:

```
margin-top: 45px;
```

Replace the padding in the "left-corner" div with this:

```
padding: 0px 25px 5em 35px;
```

Now, you can lower the pixels in the height property of the "header" div to bring everything up. Finally, you'll need to shrink the red background image that appears in the "wrapper" div with a simple paint program so that it doesn't clash with the rest of the content.

*Or if you want a quick and dirty fix, change the background property in the "wrapper" div to

```
background: #FBF9F2 url(body.png) repeat-x 2% -1.4%;
```